# Update OS X without using discrete graphics card

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, graphics, kernel-panic, gpu

I have a Macbook Pro late 2011 and my discrete GPU stopped working about a month ago, so now I have to use the Intel HD Graphics 3000 card only.

Anyway, I've deleted some kexts related to my old *AMD Radeon 6750M*, which doesn't work anymore and I use gfxCardStatus to block my mac from switching GPUs, and sometimes I just leave it with dynamic switching. It never switched GPUs after deleting these kexts (but the GPU is still recognizable through *About This Mac*)...

What I want to know is: Can I update my Mac OS X operating system without creating these kexts again or using the dedicated GPU?

I don't know if updating it will generate new kexts so my Mac will try to use the dedicated video card during the update process and mess with everything, but I need to update since I'm currently using Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite DP8 which is unstable.

Can someone help me?

Comment: That is not possible to selectively install drivers with new OS install. As long your device is registered in the hardware profile the drivers will be installed.

Comment: Isn't there some way to prevent the OS from using the dedicated GPU while updating?

Comment: Probably there it is, but sure more complicated then removing the drivers afterward.